# How to access the RecycleBin or trash folders and recover deleted files?

Tags: data-recovery

Deleted a file, with the option to delete permanently unchecked. Tried to retrieve it then, only to find out that Android has no visible recycle bin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deleting files with the option to delete permanently unchecked, they do go to a `RecycleBin` folder or `trash` folder if you delete them using an app that lets you see the files you deleted.
There are actually ways that allow you to access and browse those folders and all invisible folders, even without root access, you can recover images this way using [DiskDigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.defianttech.diskdigger).

Answer (score 2):

Android has no "Trash Folder". Maybe your file manager provides one but with no info provided, we cannot determine how it is. Usually unchecking such an option like "Delete Permanently" just disables file shredding, which is far different from moving to a "Trash Folder".

Comment: I have Asus ZenFone Selfie (Z00UD) with Android 6.0.1.
And it allows to view deleted photos from the gallery by unchecking such option, hence my assumption. I thought that there should be a different app to see more files besides photos.

Comment: Very sadly the feature of keeping deleted photos is provided by the specific gallery app, not the Android OS. AFAIK *very* few apps have such a feature.